# AlarmManager for calling a service in Android P: startForegroundService

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager as below and its working fine for Android O and below.

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i=new Intent(context, PeriodicChecksService.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + firstGoOffTime, frequencyInMS , pi);
```

But in Android P am getting the below error in Logcat:

> Background start not allowed: service Intent { flg=0x4
>   cmp=com.app.appname/.PeriodicChecksService (has extras) } to
>   com.app.recorder/.PeriodicChecksService from pid=-1 uid=10321
>   pkg=com.app.appname startFg?=false

I believe its because we have to use `startForegroundService` while starting a service. How do we do that in AlarmManager?

Answer (score 1):

After Android O, you can use [`PendingIntent.getForegroundService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getForegroundService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)).

> Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a foreground service, like calling Context.startForegroundService(). The start arguments given to the service will come from the extras of the Intent.