# About abnormal termination when upgrading the targetSdkVersion from API 30 to 31 while waiting for an alarm on the Android 12 emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Put the setAlarmClock of the Android11 (API30) target resource on standby in the Android Emulator of Android12 (API31).
Close the app.
Upgrade to Android12 (API31) target resource.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.xxx.xxx.AlarmReceiver: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.xxx.xxx/.AlarmService

The above error occurs.

It operates normally when the above conditions are not met.

Below is the source.

```
am.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(alarmRun, showIntent1), pendingIntent2);
```

Receiver

```
context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, AlarmService.class));
```

Is it a bug in the Android Emulator?

Will the situation be the same on the actual machine?

I can't test because I don't own the actual Android 12.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70044393/fatal-android-12-exception-startforegroundservice-not-allowed-due-to-mallows

Comment: Your app invokes an exact alarm to complete an action that the user requests. It works fine except in the state of the question.