# Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false when triggered from Activity.onStop

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

After exhaustive investigation based on similar issues, I have to try and get some input on my specific case.

I have an Android application that consists of an activity and a service. When the activity is started, I start the service (as a normal background service) by calling startService(). When the user closes the app (so in Activity.onStop) I move the Service to a foreground service, by calling startForeground with an appropriate notification. Usually this works fine. But I do occasionally get `ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException` with `Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false` reported.

I cannot reproduce this on locally (either debug or production). From the crash logs, this does not seem to affect all users, and the users that are affected only see this occasionally.

As far as I can gather, I am following the correct steps to handle this, as is evidenced by the fact that it works in most cases.

I have tried `builder.setForegroundServiceBehavior(Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE);` and the service is declared as `android:foregroundServiceType="location"`

My best guess was that in some cases the StartForeground isn't called quickly enough (as I understand the OS gives a short window to do this type of switch), but I cannot confirm this. Also in OnStop, I call this immediately, and the notification is pre-created, so I don't know how this could be sped up?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is already in the background when this exception is thrown. You'll have to start the foreground `Service` **before your app goes to the background**. See [Fatal Android 12: Exception: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70044393/fatal-android-12-exception-startforegroundservice-not-allowed-due-to-mallows) and https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions

As a workaround, you might try setting the `Service` to a foreground `Service` in `onPause()` instead of `onStop()` and return it to a background `Service` in `onResume()`. That might be a way to work around this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I had considered this before, but as per the issue in your first link: 
In the following situations, your app can start foreground services even while your app is running in the background:

Your app transitions from a user-visible state, such as an activity.

My assumption is that I am in this state, but I suppose this might not be.

With regards to using onPaused, I tried that but it seems samsung devices call onpaused when taskmanager is opened, pixel does not, so it leads to some inconsistencies....however, this might have to be the route I take at the end

Comment: Question: How are you calling `startForeground()` from an `Activity`? Normally the `Service` needs to call `startForeground()` itself. Please explain.

Comment: I have a bound service and expose a public function to tell the service to call startForeground.

Comment: Perhaps the time allowed to call startForeground starts when onPaused is hit, and then by the time onStop is hit this time has elapsed? This also clarifies why it happens infrequently, as there are limited cases where onStop isn't called directly after onPause.

Comment: That sounds correct. `onPause()` is called immediately when the `Activity` is covered (by another `Activity` or another app). `onStop()` is treated more like a cleanup function and is called "whenever the framework gets around to it".

Comment: I just did some testing, and this does not appear to be the case. Although the I do see _Application going to background_ in logcat, if I try to show the foreground notification from this state it is still allowed. More definitive testing might be needed. 

As an alternate solution, is there any harm to just ALWAYS have the service running as foreground? Not a fan of this visually, but would it be technically OK?

Comment: Yes, you can always have the service running as a foreground `Service`. There's no reason not to (other than the Notification requirement for foreground services)