# Users crashing because of Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false only on Anddroid 14

Tags: android, android-service, android-14

I just released an update targeting API 34 and suddenly I'm getting this exception and it is happening 100% only on Android 14 devices.

```
Caused by android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service mypackage.myservice
       at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:54)
       at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:50)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal(Parcel.java:4882)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:4864)
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3064)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:7214)
       at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:862)
```

My code didn't really change for the `startForeground` call.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK);
    }else{
        service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

Also, this is only happening on crashlytics, I haven't been able to reproduce it myself, the service starts fine for me.

And yes I have gone through the Play Store App content declaration for foreground services and it was accepted.

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Android 12: Exception: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70044393/fatal-android-12-exception-startforegroundservice-not-allowed-due-to-mallows)

Comment: Not exactly, but I'm not sure. Two things that are different, all my exceptions are android 14 and also I can't reproduce the issue, I only see it on crashlytics.

Comment: In my case, I was able to reproduce the issue by playing music, sending the app to the background, then initiating and rejecting a call. As the audio focus returned and the app tried to startForeground while in the background, that's when the problem occurred. @casolorz

Comment: What is your solution in that case? For me it could be that it is moving to a new media item and trying to stop and then restart the service.